# Using bash variables in arguments in Google Cloud Build provider

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp

Here is one of my steps in the cloud build trigger.

```
step {
      name = "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"       
entrypoint = "bash"
      args = ["-c", "docker", "build", "-t", "gcr.io/something:$(date +%m.%d)", "."]          
    }
```

It applies properly, but when I try to run the trigger, it complains about having a bad tag name.
`failed to find one or more images after execution of build steps:`

Comment: It looks like you forgot one "{" braket. Should be something like  args = ["-c", "docker", "build", "-t", "gcr.io/something:${(date +%m.%d)}", "."]

Comment: @Jaroslav I fixed the brackets. `${}` are reserved for terraform substitutions and not gcp substitutions.

Comment: (I mean bash substitutions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments shouldn't be separated.
It should look like:

```
step {
      name = "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"       
entrypoint = "bash"
      args = ["-c", "docker build -t gcr.io/something:$(date +%m.%d)} ."]         
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, remember to mark the answer as correct https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer